# How can I view old MSN Messenger, XML chat files in Ubuntu 22.04 as I used to view them in any browser in Windows?

Tags: 22.04, xml

Opening them in any browser in Ubuntu returns a blank page.

Comment: Why did the answers to my question disappear?

Comment: because it was deleted by the OP, or by a moderator.

Comment: Wo, that's just great.

Answer (score 0):

You can view those `.xml` chat logs in **LibreOffice Calc**, and possibly in other similar spreadsheet applications, by following the below steps:

1. From the menu bar, choose `Data` > `XML Source...`
2. Pick the `.xml` log file as the `Source File`. This shows the structure of the XML file as an expandable tree view in the `Map to Document` pane in the dialog window.
3. Click on the `Message` element in the XML tree.
4. Then click on a cell in the spreadsheet that will be the top left cell of the table that will be inserted in the spreadsheet, which would normally be the `A1` cell in a blank spreadsheet document that is opened only to insert the chat log.

And as the result of these steps, the `.xml` file is parsed and inserted in the spreadsheet as a table with ten columns.

Dates and times of messages are listed separately in the `Date` and `Time` columns, and also in a combined format in the `DateTime` column, the sender and receiver are shown in the two `FriendlyName` columns, and the `Text` column lists the messages. Any other undesired columns can be deleted. More details on importing XML data in a LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet can be found in the [LibreOffice documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/xml_source.html)

Alternatively, the `xmlstarlet` utility, which is provided by the official repositories of many distributions including Ubuntu, can be used on the command line to query the XML log file for the desired elements and save the conversation as a plain text file as shown below:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m /Log//Message \
    -o '[' \
    -v From/User/@FriendlyName \
    -o ' ' \
    -v @Date \
    -o ' ' \
    -v @Time \
    -o ']' -n \
    -v Text -n -n '/path/to/msnlog.xml' > msnlog.txt
```

After the above command is executed, contents of the `msnlog.txt` file looks like this:

```
[Person1 2023-09-21 03:03:48]
Hi

[Person2 2023-09-21 03:03:49]
Hello
```